# Why is a canvas line rendered below the initial page load have lower fidelity than those above?

Tags: html, canvas, paperjs

I am using paper.js to manage my html5 drawing.  In Chrome if I reload at the bottom of the page and view this line, it is clear:

[image: image1]

If I reloaded at the bottom, I can scroll up and back down, and the line will maintain its fidelity.

But if I reload at the top of the page and scroll down, the line looks jagged and not anti-aliased, like so:

[image: image2]

Strangely, if I scroll up and down a few times after initially loading at the top of the page, the fidelity gets worse:

[image: image3]

This happens in Safari as well, and in Firefox it happens but almost to an unnoticeable degree.  My assumption is that this has something to do with the fact that when I load at the bottom, all of the dom elements above the load are rendered at page load.  Whereas if I load at the top, the elements are only rendered when scrolled into view (and so are fighting with the scroll event and repaints for CPU?)

But is there anything I can do to make sure all dom events are rendered at page load?  I am already wrapping the initial draw function in a $(document).ready.

Comment: That's an odd effect for sure. Do you have a link to see this in action?

Comment: That reminds me of the line drawing here: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/ which gains increased graininess due to the repeated stroking of the line. Can you review your code for `stroke()` and see if that's tied to any event that would fire more than once?

Comment: I thought that too, but I put a logger on the function where I draw the paths and it is only called once.  I do set and unset the visibility of the paths, but when I turn that off and leave them static, the same problem occurs.  I put the page up on s3 to show you the issue:

Comment: http://testcanvas.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/portfolio.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is simply related to performance (I haven't profiled it yet, so I'm not sure whether CPU or memory are the limiting factor).  But I can simply add a calculation to console.log in an onFrame loop, and the lines will appear jagged despite there being no html5 initiated animation or redrawing on the screen.

Edit:

The real problem turned out that adding resize to the canvas tag like:

```
<canvas resize></canvas>
```

will cause everything under a certain point in the page to be redrawn kind of wonkily.